# (Tensorflow)Does the op assign change the gradient computation?

Tags: tensorflow

I use the op "assign" to change the value of variables instead of "=", but I found the gradient I got is quite different. Could anyone tell me the difference and why? thanks!
Like change *w = w1* to *op1 = tf.assign(w, w1) sess.run(op1)*

Answer (score 1):

`=` and `tf.assign` are different operations.

`=` is a **python** operation, in which you assign a python value to a python variable

`tf.assign` is a Tensorflow operation that assigns the value to the variable ref and returns the **assign operation**.

`=` is executed in python and doesn't affect the computation graph.
`tf.assign` is a node in the computational graph.

To understand, let's run this simple script

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
y = tf.Variable(2)

x = y

print(x.name, y.name)

a = tf.Variable(1)
b = tf.Variable(2)

# override a, otherwise a content is 1
a = a.assign(b)
print(a.name, b.name)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run([x, y, a, b]))
```

`print(x.name, y.name)` outputs `Variable_1:0 Variable_1:0`

because `=` is executed in python and you've overwritten the variable `x`.

`print(a.name, b.name)` outputs `Assign:0 Variable_3:0` because you defined an assign op in the computational graph, now `a` is an assign op.

When you run the defined graph, you get:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

But these values are computed differently: one is a computation in the graph, the others no.

If you forgot to assign `a` to the **assign op** created with `tf.assign` (thus you change the line `a = a.assign(b)` to `a.assign(b)`), then when you evaluate the graph, you'll get:

```
[2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.But could you please tell me how the op assign will contribute to the gradient computation? I am really confused about this.

Comment: Actually i want to change the value of variables without change the gradient computation,

Comment: If it's  used properly it does not change the gradient computation. Tensorflow uses the automatic differentiation to compute the gradient, so an assign op simply creates a new node in the computational graph that contains the assigned variable. If you calculate the gradient flowing trouhg this node, it will pass without any changes. Usually you see differences in gradient results if you confuse assign and = ops, because you're making mess with the graphs nodes

Comment: `w = tf.Variable(weights,name='w'+str(i),dtype='float32')
w1 = binary(w)
w = w1`
How to change this with op assign?(I want to make the gradient computation the same)

Thank you for your reply.

binary is like

`def binary(w):
    G = tf.get_default_graph()
    with G.gradient_override_map({"Sign": "Identity"}):
        E = tf.stop_gradient(tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(w)))
        return tf.sign(w / E) * E`

Comment: You could try with `w = tf.identity(w1)`, since you want `w` to be the same as `w1`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But actually what i want to do is that at first, I build the graph, and then change the value of the variable without changing the gradient computation at each epoch.So could you please give me some suggestions?