# How tf.assign compute gradients in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose the following simplified code:

```
x = tf.Variable(...)
y = tf.Variable(...)  # y can also be some tensor computed from other variables
x_new = tf.assign(x, y)
loss = x_new * x_new
```

If I optimize loss, does the gradient of loss be back-propagated to x or y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can find a pretty good explanation of assign op in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116260/tensorflowdoes-the-op-assign-change-the-gradient-computation).

For your specific question, the gradient of loss will not be back-propagated to x or y:

```
# Your example.
tf.gradients(x_new * x_new, [x, y]) #output: [None, None]

# Some other related examples.
tf.gradients(x_new * y, [x, y]) #output: [None, x_new_value]
tf.gradients(x * x_new, [x, y]) #output: [x_new_value, None]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I'm still confused. Although tf.gradients(x_new, [x,y]) is [None, None], both x_new and x refers to the same underlying variable/parameter (the output of [assign op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/state_ops.cc) is a ref type). During optimization, will the gradients from x and x_new be accumulated together to update the underlying parameter?

Comment: No, x_new and x refers to different things.  while x refers to the variable, x_new refers to the assign_op that takes x and y as inputs.  As in the recommended discussion, this op will not back-propagate its gradients to its inputs.  Therefore, gradients from x and x_new be NOT accumulated together. Does that make sense?