# Does slicing a tensor provide gradients in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to slice 1024x1024 image tensor to 16 tensors of size 256x256. I'm doing it with this code:

```
with tf.variable_scope("image_split", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    img_array = tf.get_variable(name = 'img_array', shape = (16, 256, 256, 3),
                                dtype = tf.float32)     
with tf.control_dependencies([img_array[i].assign(img[(i%4)*256:(i%4+1)*256, 
    (i//4)*256:((i+4)//4)*256]) for i in range(16)]):
        img_array = tf.identity(img_array)
```

But I receive this error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients`

If I don't slice image everything works normally. Does slicing a tensor provide gradients? If yes what is a correct way to do it?

Comment: Please include a call to tf.gradients. Otherwise, it's unclear what you're trying to differentiate wrt what.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev I don't have a call to tf.gradients. I'm trying to minimize the difference between images with optimizer.minimize. Final goal is to find latent representation of the large image in GAN network. But do it while comparing small images. So I'm slicing large image into small ones and receiving this error.

Comment: Seems that the problem is with tf.assign operation that does not provide gradients as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984316/how-tf-assign-compute-gradients-in-tensorflow). Does anybody know how to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have to call assign? Could you instead use a Python (i.e. graph-build-time) variable?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev No. Since one image comes from a generator and is a Tensor. So I need to slice tensors and assign the values to new variables.

Comment: You could try using TensorArray instead of a Python array. TensorArray allows gradients to flow through writes and reads.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev I changed the code to use TensorArray like this: 
`for i in range(16):
  img_array1.write(i, tf.expand_dims(generated_img[0][(i%4) * 256 : (i%4+1) * 256,
                                          (i//4) * 256 : ((i+4)//4) * 256], axis = 0))` Then I do the same for the second image and then I read small images one by one and calculate perceptual loss for them. But it still throws the same error:  `No gradients provided for any variable.`

Comment: Please update your question and consider including a reproducer. Note also that TensorArray.write returns a new array, so you have to do `img_array1 = img_array1.write(...)`.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Yes, it works! Thanks a lot!